# Mouse cursor over a picture box. Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, mouseover, picturebox

I have an exam coming up in Visual Basic so I'm trying to bite through the tasks given in lessons.

What I have to do, basically, is create a form with pictureboxes on top of it and every time the mouse goes on top of the picture box it adds +1 to a counter and while on top of the picture, it adds to a time counter.

I can grasp how to manage the counters but have no idea how to do the mousecontrol. Is there a function for that and if there is how exactly does it execute in the given situation.

I did find this:

- [Cursor.Position Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

but unsure whether it's the function I should be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of PictureBox. That event will raised whenever *the mouse goes on top of the picture box*, exactly as you want. And you may also want to listen to [MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, to stop the time counter when the mouse leave from top of picture box.

**UPDATE :** some more explanation as per request

Register an event handler to handle MouseEnter event. Refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984320%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) if you're not sure how. In the MouseEnter event handler sub, you can put your logic to modify counter and starting a timer (if I don't misunderstood the *"time counter"* you mentioned).

Then register another event handler to handle MouseLeave event. In this handler, you put codes to stop that timer I mentioned above.

Comment: could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @Triinu see my update. I get the question as "where to put my logic for adding counter and time counter" and my answer is in `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` event rather then in `CursorMove`. That's clear enough I think..

Comment: Thanks a lot. After messing around with it for half an hour got it to work perfectly.